# What is a splice in spools of tubular webbing?

Tags: gear, rock-climbing

While trying to answer [Why static rope rather than webbing for toprope anchors?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/11362/why-static-rope-rather-than-webbing-for-toprope-anchors) I immediately thought about splices in long pieces of webbing. For example, [REI](https://www.rei.com/product/737298/bluewater-1-climb-spec-tubular-webbing) says that spools of Blue Water webbing may not be continuous, although I cannot find a reference on Blue Water's site.

I haven't worked with spools of webbing in a long time. My recollection is that a spool typically had 3 or so splices that were marked with tape an a pin. We use to cut around them, when making shorter slings. I do not remember how much space we left. My recollection was that apart from the pin/tape, there was no visual indication of the splice.

I cannot find any information about splices. I guess I have 4 related questions.

Do spools of webbing still have splices?

How weak is the splice?

How big is the section of weakness?

What do splices look like?

Comment: Should these be separate questions?

Comment: @ChrisMendez possibly, but I see them as guiding the answer to the titular question.

Comment: Have a look at my previous answer at http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/6435/climbing-webbing-with-taped-ends-where-why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Do spools of webbing still have splices?***

**Yes.** As [Paul's answer](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/6437/3066) pointed out, there was [a well-known accident](http://publications.americanalpineclub.org/articles/13200106101/) caused by a climber purchasing webbing with a tape splice in the middle.

Furthermore, multiple retailers have various warnings that spools may contain up to three sections (ie, two splices) per 300ft spool of 1in webbing.

http://www.cmcrescue.com/equipment/tubular-webbing/

> Note: Military standards allow for up to three sections per spool.

http://www.strapworks.com/Flat_Nylon_Webbing_p/fnw1.htm

> For most webbing the maximum continuous length is 150ft, after which a new roll is started.

***How weak is the splice?***

It's just two pieces of webbing taped together. The tape's stickiness is unknown, so it should be considered to have an effective breaking strength of **0lbs (0kN)**.

However, [in actual tests](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/552e8f43e4b07f0b3920027b/t/566b4fd7841abafcc8ddb684/1449873367506/AnalysisHappyHour1.pdf) (slide 13) by Rocky Mountain Rescue Group, tape splices break **around 25lbs (0.11kN)**:

> Result 1
>   : Adhesive failure, tape intact, webbing pulled out, 20-25lbs (0.08-0.11kN).
>
> Result 2
>   :  Tape tore (see photograph), adhesive held, 24-28lbs (0.10-0.12kN).

***How big is the section of weakness?***

Presumably only the **tape-covered portion** of the splice is effected.

***What do splices look like?***

Like this:

[image: picture of spliced webbing]

Comment: Would love to see a splice before breaking.

Comment: I suggest adding a sentence to the taped strength number of 0.11kN in the likes of: "This strength is just enough to maybe hold a person statically, but will break on the slightest additional load." Just to add a warning in prose alongside the number.

Comment: There are also stitched splices - http://www.bethandevans.com/pdf/OnRope.pdf

Comment: @RussellSteen stitched splices are different and I do not think are ever used on a spool of webbing. A stitched splice, for example, would be used in place of a water knot to create a loop.

Comment: @StrongBad -- A couple of sites I read indicated that stitches were sometimes used in "factory splices", but I'm hardly an expert :)